# Jenkinsfile 'parallel' directive

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to write a `Jenkinsfile` that executes in parallel a sequence of steps. The goal is to have two `agents` (aka. `nodes`). One should do a windows build and the other a linux build. However I do not want this to happen sequentially but in parallel. I am trying to find documentation for the `parallel` directive that is described in [Pipeline - Parallel execution of tasks](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230922168-Pipeline-Parallel-execution-of-tasks).

I found one occurence of `parallel` one on the Jenkins, but it seems the documentation is broken: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/

```
parallel: Execute in parallel

org.kohsuke.stapler.NoStaplerConstructorException: 
    There’s no @DataBoundConstructor on any constructor of class
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.steps.ParallelStep
```

How should I setup a Jenkinsfile that can execute a series of build steps on two different agents (one linux, one windows) in parallel?

In particular, should I rather use the declarative or script based pipeline DSL?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use either declarative or script based for doing parallel work. The script based docs for parallel can be found here: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#advanced-scripted-pipeline

They give the following example...

```js
stage('Build') {
    /* .. snip .. */
}

stage('Test') {
    parallel linux: {
        node('linux') {
            checkout scm
            try {
                unstash 'app'
                sh 'make check'
            }
            finally {
                junit '**/target/*.xml'
            }
        }
    },
    windows: {
        node('windows') {
            /* .. snip .. */
        }
    }
}
```

For declarative, I believe you'll do this:

```js
stage('Build') {
    steps {
        parallel (
            "Windows" : {
                echo 'done'
            },
            "Linux" : {
                echo 'done'
            }
        )
     }
}
```

Since **Declarative Pipeline 1.2**, the preferred declarative syntax is:

```js
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Run Tests') {
            parallel {
                stage('Test On Windows') {
                    agent {
                        label "windows"
                    }
                    steps {
                        bat "run-tests.bat"
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                            junit "**/TEST-*.xml"
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Test On Linux') {
                    agent {
                        label "linux"
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh "run-tests.sh"
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                            junit "**/TEST-*.xml"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I put multiple stages into the parallel directive? For example to do checkout, build and test in parallel on two nodes? Or is parallel not supposed to be used like this?

Comment: Also in the given scripted example, assuming in the `build` stage I also put a `parallel` directive to build on multiple nodes in parallel, then the `test` stage would wait until all parallel tasks in the `build` stage have completed, which means the slowest node defines when the build can move to the next stage, is that right?

Comment: You can put multiple stages in there with the scripted one, unsure on the declarative pipelines. Multiple stages in the parallel steps can make the UI do funny things, and Blue Ocean doesn't support it in the UI if I remember correctly.

To your second question, yes, the pipeline script will not continue until all the sections of a set of parallel tasks have completed. This does mean that you are held up by the slowest node if you split up your build+test stages into two sets of parallel tasks.

Comment: @SpencerMalone Thanks man, the declarative one works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

[Declarative Matrix](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix) is a great feature for running parallel tasks. It allows you to execute the defined stages (incl. post build actions) for every configuration defined in the matrix directive *without* code duplication.

Example:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            matrix {
                agent {
                    label "${PLATFORM}-agent"
                }
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'PLATFORM'
                        values 'linux', 'windows'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Test') {
                        steps {
                            echo "Do Test for ${PLATFORM}"
                        }
                    }
                }
                post {
                    always {
                        junit "**/TEST-*.xml"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Quote from a Jenkins [blog post](https://jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/):

> An equivalent pipeline created without matrix would easily be several
>   times larger, and much harder to understand and maintain.

Comment: As the name implies, this only works in Declarative pipelines.